# Does Dynamic Harmonic regression need to be linear?

Tags: r, dynamic, regression

when I study dynamic harmonic regression I know it is the combination of the regression with ARIMA error, so I am confuse that does the dynamic harmonic regreesion also need to be linear?

it need to be linear or not? please tell me that!

Comment: Hi Ke Chang! Welcome to StackOverflow! This question probably belongs on stats.stackexchange.com